# jQuery Performance Issues When Checking For Duplicates

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jsp, html-table

I have an html table that is populated with a product list when a user uploads a CSV file.  Often, the table will have over a thousand rows.  The problem is, when the user clicks "submit" I have to check for duplicate entries in one of the inputs for every row.  This takes an extremely long amount of time and often times I get the unresponsive script warning.

Here is the script I'm using to check for duplicates:

```
// Check for duplicate products
    $('#match_table').submit(function(evt) {
        var arr = document.getElementsByName("pid[]");
        var sorted_arr =  new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            sorted_arr[i] = new Array();
            sorted_arr[i][0] = arr[i].value;
            sorted_arr[i][1] = arr[i].id;
        }
        sorted_arr.sort((function(index){
            return function(a, b){
                return (a[index] === b[index] ? 0 : (a[index] < b[index] ? -1 : 1));
            };
        })(0));
        var results = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < sorted_arr.length - 1; i++) {
            if (sorted_arr[i + 1][0] == sorted_arr[i][0]) {
                results.push(sorted_arr[i][0]);
                evt.preventDefault();
                document.getElementById(sorted_arr[i][1]).style.border = "1px solid red";
                document.getElementById(sorted_arr[i+1][1]).style.border = "1px solid red";
            }
        }
        if(results.length != 0){
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Any ideas/examples on how to improve performance on this script?  Or how to get around this problem?

Edit: Snippet of the HTML

```
<form id="match_table" action="tool_tmaxupload.jsp" name="match_table" method="post">
                <table class="nozebra">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="essential"></th>
                            <th class="essential">CSV Product</th>
                            <th class="essential">CSV Desc</th>
                            <th class="essential">Match Product</th>
                            <th class="essential">Match Desc</th>
                            <th class="essential">Match Vend</th>
                            <th class="essential">Amount</th>
                            <th class="essential">To Rebate</th>
                            <th class="essential">To Growth</th>
                            <th class="essential">Paid On What</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                                <tr class=even>
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" class="checkall"></td>
                                    <td>343601</td>
                                    <td>TEST</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" size="8" name="pid[]" id="pid_0" value="343601"/></td>
                                    <td>COMBO LUNCH MEAT</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" size="8" name="ve[]" value="672" /> FARMLAND FOODS INC</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" size="5" name="ramt[]" value="5.5"/></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="torebate[]" id="torebate">
                                            <option value="0" >No</option>
                                            <option value="1"  selected=selected>Yes</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="togrowth[]" id="togrowth">
                                            <option value="0"  selected=selected>No</option>
                                            <option value="1" >Yes</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="pow[]" id="pow">
                                            <option value="1"  selected=selected>% of FOB Cost</option>
                                            <option value="2" >% of Delivered Cost</option>
                                            <option value="3" >$ Per Case</option>
                                            <option value="4" >$ Per Pound</option>
                                            <option value="5" >% of Sold For Price</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr class=odd>
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" class="checkall"></td>
                                    <td>561720</td>
                                    <td>TEST</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" size="8" name="pid[]" id="pid_1" /></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" size="8" name="ve[]" /></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" size="5" name="ramt[]" value="6.5"/></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="torebate[]" id="torebate">
                                            <option value="0"  selected=selected>No</option>
                                            <option value="1" >Yes</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="togrowth[]" id="togrowth">
                                            <option value="0" >No</option>
                                            <option value="1"  selected=selected>Yes</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="pow[]" id="pow">
                                            <option value="1" >% of FOB Cost</option>
                                            <option value="2"  selected=selected>% of Delivered Cost</option>
                                            <option value="3" >$ Per Case</option>
                                            <option value="4" >$ Per Pound</option>
                                            <option value="5" >% of Sold For Price</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr class=even>
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" class="checkall"></td>
                                    <td>193420</td>
                                    <td>TEST</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" size="8" name="pid[]" id="pid_2" value="346770"/></td>
                                    <td>HAM SPIRAL SLIC disc use346778</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" size="8" name="ve[]" value="672" /> FARMLAND FOODS INC</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" size="5" name="ramt[]" value="7.5"/></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="torebate[]" id="torebate">
                                            <option value="0" >No</option>
                                            <option value="1"  selected=selected>Yes</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="togrowth[]" id="togrowth">
                                            <option value="0"  selected=selected>No</option>
                                            <option value="1" >Yes</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="pow[]" id="pow">
                                            <option value="1" >% of FOB Cost</option>
                                            <option value="2" >% of Delivered Cost</option>
                                            <option value="3"  selected=selected>$ Per Case</option>
                                            <option value="4" >$ Per Pound</option>
                                            <option value="5" >% of Sold For Price</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr class=even>
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" class="checkall"></td>
                                    <td>193420</td>
                                    <td>TEST</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" size="8" name="pid[]" id="pid_3" value="346771"/></td>
                                    <td>HAM SPIRAL SLICED BONE IN</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" size="8" name="ve[]" value="672" /> FARMLAND FOODS INC</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" size="5" name="ramt[]" value="7.5"/></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="torebate[]" id="torebate">
                                            <option value="0" >No</option>
                                            <option value="1"  selected=selected>Yes</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="togrowth[]" id="togrowth">
                                            <option value="0"  selected=selected>No</option>
                                            <option value="1" >Yes</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="pow[]" id="pow">
                                            <option value="1" >% of FOB Cost</option>
                                            <option value="2" >% of Delivered Cost</option>
                                            <option value="3"  selected=selected>$ Per Case</option>
                                            <option value="4" >$ Per Pound</option>
                                            <option value="5" >% of Sold For Price</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr class=odd>
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" class="checkall"></td>
                                    <td>191239</td>
                                    <td>TEST</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" size="8" name="pid[]" id="pid_4" value="346778"/></td>
                                    <td>HAM SPIRAL SLICED BONE IN</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" size="8" name="ve[]" value="672" /> FARMLAND FOODS INC</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" size="5" name="ramt[]" value="8.5"/></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="torebate[]" id="torebate">
                                            <option value="0"  selected=selected>No</option>
                                            <option value="1" >Yes</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="togrowth[]" id="togrowth">
                                            <option value="0"  selected=selected>No</option>
                                            <option value="1" >Yes</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="pow[]" id="pow">
                                            <option value="1" >% of FOB Cost</option>
                                            <option value="2" >% of Delivered Cost</option>
                                            <option value="3" >$ Per Case</option>
                                            <option value="4"  selected=selected>$ Per Pound</option>
                                            <option value="5" >% of Sold For Price</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr class=even>
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" class="checkall"></td>
                                    <td>448584</td>
                                    <td>TEST</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" size="8" name="pid[]" id="pid_5" /></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" size="8" name="ve[]" /></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" size="5" name="ramt[]" value="9.5"/></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="torebate[]" id="torebate">
                                            <option value="0" >No</option>
                                            <option value="1"  selected=selected>Yes</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="togrowth[]" id="togrowth">
                                            <option value="0" >No</option>
                                            <option value="1"  selected=selected>Yes</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="pow[]" id="pow">
                                            <option value="1"  selected=selected>% of FOB Cost</option>
                                            <option value="2" >% of Delivered Cost</option>
                                            <option value="3" >$ Per Case</option>
                                            <option value="4" >$ Per Pound</option>
                                            <option value="5" >% of Sold For Price</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <th colspan="10"><input type="hidden" name="rbid" value="10034" /></th>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                </table>
                <input class="check" type="button" value="Check all" />
                <input id="AddRow" type="button" value="Add">
                <input id="DeleteRow" type="button" value="Delete">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Load" />
            </form>
```

Comment: Would this question benefit more being asked on [**SO-CodeReview**](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Good question. Never heard of SO-CodeReview.

Comment: Why don't you do the checks serverside? I mean I guess you are using a database for storing the uploaded .csv?

Comment: Validation should be carried out on the server side. It should only be done on the client side if it is better for the usability of the application/website but should always be checked when submitted to the server as client side code can easily be changed.

Comment: Because they can manipulate the data after they upload the csv and it needs to check for duplicates and alert them to change them when they hit the submit button.

Comment: Can you post an html snippet showing a sample of 10 items perhaps? I'd like to see the DOM you are dealing with.

Comment: @Tmac: that doesn't change anything. When they submit the form after having modified some data, the form is submitted to the server, and the server should validate the input.

Comment: @JBNizet - then I suppose just redirect back to the page highlighting the offending inputs, if any?

Comment: I would forward rather than redirect, but yes, that's the idea. You can't trust what comes from the browser. The user might disable JavaScript and submit whatever he wants.